# We need an [admin] or [administrator] to burninate this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I suggest abolishing the [admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin) and [administrators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administrators) tags. It is not a valid topic on which anyone can be an expert or would have an interest in following.

It currently has about 4,300 questions, most of which are related to web development and have other relevant tags.

Comment: I think we should also burninate [tag:administration].

Comment: Still I do not think that we need [tag:admin]. This burnination request could be reconsidered again...

Comment: Lets burn some [admin]'s! Maybe a new tag [tag:django-admin] could be created? Edit: [tag:django-admin] already exists - maybe a burnination is not needed .

Comment: @KeithPinson And fire the [tag:administrator]s as well :)

Answer (score 6):

The usual four-of-a-kind:

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

  It definitely is ambiguous. A web admin interface is nowhere like the same thing as a database admin or Windows elevated privileges. And it's sometimes [borderline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66562911/5958455) or just [outright](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66648938/5958455) [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51494630/5958455).
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

  The concept "admin" by itself is not even on-topic for SO. It's definitely better on SU or SF.
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

  The majority of its appearance goes alongside [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django), which is a good indication that [django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-admin) should have a better [raison d'être](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre).
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

  See point 1.

Comment: [tag:django-admin] already exists - would it be useful to synonymize [tag:admin] with [tag:django-admin] and then replace it in all posts?

Comment: @10Rep There's a considerable portion of posts using [tag:admin] for the other meanings mention here. Not a good idea to blindly synonymize them.