# Should we delete the [string] and [array] tags because they have no experts?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

[Many burninate requests argue that if no one is an expert in a given tag, we should burninate.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=burninate%20expert) If this is true, should we burninate [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) and [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) as well? No one's *really* a [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) expert IMHO, and I doubt many people search [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) to find questions to answer. Nonetheless I think these tags can be useful:

1. They make it easy to find [questions involving strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+string)
2. While I'm not a string expert, I *could* be a java string expert, and having a [java-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-string) tag seems silly.

How should we evaluate tags like these that only make sense alongside other tags? For example, should [this [internet] burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255169/i-want-to-delete-the-internet) take into account the fact that a Java question tagged [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet) probably has a different focus than one only tagged java?

---

EDIT: I mention [string] and [array] to debate the "burn it if it has no experts!" philosophy rather than their tag-destinies (although the two are pretty related...).

Comment: You can `AND` tags together when you search, so presumably a tag that has no intrinsic value on its own gains some value in conjunction with others.

Comment: [Tags should generally be able to stand on their own.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) That said, someone could ask a question about array implementation strategies or how to effeciently parse a string (in no particular language). Both tags *could* stand on there own, though I've never seen it.

Comment: @roippi: You can search for keywords as well as tags.

Comment: @JDB While I agree, you *could* make the same argument for [run] and [statement]. Is it possible for someone to come up with a language-agnostic question about program statements? Sure, it probably *possible*, but that doesn't mean we should keep the tag. The real reason for having [string] and [array] isn't that they could stand alone, but that they help describe the question. Is this enough to keep them, or should we rely on titles/body content instead?

Comment: Relevant: [admin tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254551/792066). Who's a admin expert? D:

Comment: Removing those 2 is a slippery slope leading to the removal of [tag:list], [tag:linked-list], [tag:class], [tag:function], [tag:method], [tag:struct], [tag:switch-statement], [tag:object], [tag:static], [tag:null], etc., etc. I'm still just not quite sure whether it's a good slippery slope or a bad slippery slope.

Comment: *"Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer"* seems like a good way to use them.  But some tags might be useful simply *to categorize a question*.  Is it possible that tags might have more than one function?  Should we burn a *useful* categorization tag just because it has no experts?

Comment: One question to consider with regards to any given tag is whether a search for the tag is (a) going to be useful and (b) going to be more or less effective than a search for the corresponding word.  In this case, [java]+[string] seems potentially useful and [java]+string is not an effective substitute (too many false positives).

Comment: Are these, effectively, [Meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)? It seems that way to me. But, cleaning them out would be a massive undertaking.

Comment: "I doubt many people search array to find questions to answer." While technically true, I do actually use the [string] and [list] tags just to get a refreshing view of questions.

Comment: All the answerers agree that these are useful tags, but no one has addressed the fact that this question is about the logic and how that logic gets applied to other tags.

Comment: They are _not_ meta tags. @ChrisBaker; meta tags are [tags which describe not the subject of the question but the question itself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273082). "[beginner]", "[eli5]", and "[resource-request]" are meta tags. "[string]" is absolutely not.

Answer (score 20):

The truth is, nobody can be an expert in strings or arrays or whatever, since they are implemented differently in each language.

However, they are useful. As @roippi pointed out, you can search with them in connection with other languages (I highly doubt that anyone searches for ex. [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)+[internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet)). In addition, if someone sees a question tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) and knows nothing about arrays in java, he doesn't have to look at that question.

Imagine the work needed to rename them to [java-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-string), [java-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-array) and so on... What if it is a general question about arrays, without a language mentioned?

So:

- Nobody can be an expert in these tags
- They are useful
- The work needed to burninate/rename them is much higher than the profit of doing it

Answer (score 8):

Yes, people CAN be expert in strings, [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) should stay.

There are a number of string-processing algorithms (things like Levenshtein distance or Rabin-Karp search) with applicability to almost any language, and someone absolutely can be an expert in these string-processing techniques.

It may be true that most [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) questions deal more with details of a particular string type and language-specific functions... but that doesn't mean that generic cross-language string questions can't exist.

Answer (score 6):

Say I am leaning F# and having problems understanding how arrays work.   I would start with looking at all questions tagged F#, then select [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array).

However it is true that there will be no experts in [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array).

On balance I think this set of tags should remain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we should burn them all (including [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list), [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list), [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack), [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queue) and [vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector)).

Let's compare these tags against [the reasons we tag questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/206447).

#### Tags connect experts with questions they will be able to answer.

Nope.

Any experienced programmer should have extensive experience with these basic data structures yet be unable to answer a question about it in a language they don't understand and anyone who calls themselves an expert in just about any language should be extensively familiar with these basic concepts in that language*.

Thus the language tag would be a much better indicator of whether someone will be able to answer a question tagged with one of these tags.

*: I'm open to the idea that there are languages out there where these are advanced concepts, and that having these tags in those languages would be useful, but, if that's the case, I'd be inclined to say we should create language specific versions of this tag, to prevent it being used in e.g. Java or C++.

#### Tags are for sorting your question into specific, well-defined categories.

Nope.

"My question involves a String" tells you practically nothing in a Java question (most Java code uses Strings somewhere). "My question is about a String" tells you more, but it's still not particularly specific - are you trying to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-search), [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace), [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting), [compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-comparison), [concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-concatenation), [find the length of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-length), [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-split), [pass to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameter-passing) or [return from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/return) a function, [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-read) or write to [a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) or [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-input) [console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console-output) or something else? Way too broad, and each of those things already has one or more tags dedicated to it.

Are there language-agnostic questions about arrays or strings? Maybe, but these are probably mostly about [array-algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-algorithms) or [string-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-algorithm) instead.

#### Tags are used in searching.

Maybe, but...

> Tags are not for summarizing your question. That's what the title and the abstract are for.
> Tags are not for indexing your question.

You should search for `[java] sort array`, not `[java] [sorting] [arrays]`. I don't think [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) has any benefit in terms of searching here.