# Should we burn [sudoku]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request, tag-wiki

The tag wiki for [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) describes the puzzle sudoku, obviously. However, do we really need *meta tags* describing the game the asker is trying to make?

As for it being a meta tag, if you saw a question only tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you would know it's about C++. Why? C++ *isn't* a meta tag. With that logic, if you saw a question just tagged [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku), does that tell you anything *helpful*? No. That's why it's a meta tag.

Comment: I think it would be useful to identify questions where someone is trying to program a sudoku puzzle, so I don't think it should be burninated.

Comment: But do we really need that?

Comment: Well 269 questions as of right now think it is, but I suppose some investigation is in order.  Maybe you could survey those and see if the tag is used correctly.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Can you provide some insight on why we wouldn't need it?

Comment: Where do you get 269? I read only 33

Comment: @ColeJohnson 33 is on the frequent tab, there are 269 total questions tagged with it.

Comment: Well I can't investigate now really. I'm on my phone. But I will later.

Comment: @bluefeet Should there be a tag for any type or category of program someone could be working on?

Comment: @joran I am not saying that.  I am saying that this tag might be valid.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I see 269 as well (on the right sidebar: "269 questions tagged [tag:sudoku]")

Comment: As a sidenote, none of the questions tagged sudoku seem to get any upvotes--most cut even or get downvoted

Comment: @JimHurley If you clock on the "votes" tab you can see that almost half of the questions have a total vote count between 54 and 1.

Comment: @madth3 the one with 54 (now 55) upvotes is because it deals with image processing on a sudoku puzzle. It could easily apply to any rectangle with the lack of code specific to sudoku.

Comment: "With that logic, if you saw a question just tagged sudoku, does that tell you anything helpful?" Yes - it tells me it's about sudoko, which has a bunch of associated algorithms. It's very much like the [tag:parsing] tag - a specific problem domain that has good and bad ways of doing things. It's helpful if you add a language tag too, but that doesn't make the tag a meta tag.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A tag that indicates the problem the asker is trying to solve? BURN THIS HEATHEN TAG!

Naw, just kidding. That's what tags are for.

> [How can you tell you're using a meta-tag?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) It’s easier than you might think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

So far as I can tell, [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) does not meet either of those criteria. It clearly identifies a specific set of problems and folks use it more or less exclusively to refer to those problems.

Comment: So would chess, checkers, monopoly, scrabble, clue, risk, game of life, chutes and ladders, othello, axis and allies, trivial pursuit and mancala be acceptable tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/chess

Comment: Lets say I'm a new user. I'm trying to write a PACMAN game. I tag it [tag:pacman] only. Does that help you at all? No.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 If they were common enough programming problems I'd say yes.  [`hello-world`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello-world), [`fizzbuzz`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz), [`primes`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primes), etc.

Comment: @Cole: it tells me your question is about PACMAN. Assuming it is (and assuming it's also a *programming question*), then you're off to a good start. *Most* questions can benefit from at least two tags - [tag:c++] doesn't say much by itself either - but at very least your first tag should give you a rough idea of the primary subject that your question pertains to.

Comment: now [hello-world] sounds like a questionable tag

Comment: As an aside: I really, *really* hate the "witch-hunt" aspect of all of these meta-tag discussions. It's very, very easy to identify a bad tag given the criteria outlined above - if you're struggling to apply them, then it's probably either a reasonable tag, or bad for reasons that have nothing to do with its "meta-ness"

Comment: @Shog9 way to take it literally. I meant, does it tell you you can help me just by looking at it? No. [tag:c++] tells me that if I know C++, I can help. [tag:pacman] wouldn't tell me if I can help or not.

Comment: Are you saying that there are not people with in-depth knowledge of the rules of pacman, @Cole?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I actually agree with you on that point, I just think the "can it stand on its own" rule might be a little bit too strict.  "sudoku" is a decent supporting tag.  "subjective", "programming", "beginner", etc. are not.  They don't really narrow the focus of the question.

Comment: @ColeJohnson But if you were experienced in writing sudoko solvers, the sudoku tag would definitely tell you whether you can help.

Comment: It tells you _what the question is about_, @Cole. That's what tags are for -- categorizing questions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for putting it so succinctly.

Comment: @AndrewC so if I was writing a program for a robot to count pieces of paper, I could tag it [tag:paper]? That's ridiculous.

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, you would tag that computer-vision. Since that's most likely the clear category there. Sudoku, by the very word, relates to a whole domain of game-specific game theory and accompanying solution strategies for example. Which is what would make it a good and descriptive tag.

Comment: @Bart - OK, that argument has convinced me that this tag has a place here. It would make a great answer by itself.

Comment: Perhaps the Sudoku tag's wiki should be updated to include how this tag is related to programming, such as listing some of those "game theoris" and "accompanying solution strategies", or at least a description of the mathematics behind the game.

Comment: I appreciate the comment @Cyborgx37, but given the amount of good answers, I don't feel the need to add my own. If Shog9 (or any one of the other answerers) wishes to incorporate some of my arguments into his answer, he's free to do so.

Comment: @Bart What if it doesn't use computer vision? it just runs them through a feeder? like a printer? that's not computer vision. That was my reasoning behind that.

Comment: Meh, I wouldn't know of an applicable tag off hand in that case @ColeJohnson. It doesn't invalidate the sudoku tag one bit though.

Answer (score 12):

[sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) is not a meta-tag. It adds information about the question. The user is trying to solve a problem that relates to their execution of a sudoku puzzle. I see no reason to burninate it.

Comment: I'm writing a program that calculates the amount of lint on a dryer-sheet as a function of wind force. Should I tag [dryer-sheet-lint][wind-force]?

Answer (score 11):

No, this one is a perfectly fine tag. It tells you one of the topics of the question, just like [boolean-logic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1350209+[boolean-logic]) or [code-formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A186285+%5Bcode-formatting%5D) do.

A so-called meta-tag describes what the question *is*, not what it deals with. The distinction beteween a meta-tag and a "normal" tag is whether the tag can finish the sentence "this question is about...". Clearly, "sudoku" successfully passes that test.

Comment: Except that both boolean-logic and code-formatting describe either algorithms or problems unique to the programming profession and can, thus, stand alone in describing an on-topic question. Could [tag:sudoko] do that?

Comment: We shouldn't have to affix each tag with "programming-" in order for it to make sense, @Cyborgx37 - [the programming aspect should be implicit given the site you're asking on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187585/most-question-tagged-with-photoshop-are-closed).

Comment: [meta-tag:code-formatting] is a tag from Meta Stack Overflow, @Cyborgx37, and tags are not what determine a question's on- or off-topic status. Would you be happier if the tag was [tag:automatic-sudoku-solver], which definitely _is_ a CompSci/programming problem?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I'd love to see an example of an on-topic question which includes only that tag, which couldn't really include any other tag, and which wouldn't be closed as too broad. It would prove, in my mind, that the tag can stand alone.

Comment: "can have no other tags" is *not* the criteria for a meta tag, @Cyborgx37. It's, "does not *need* any other tags".

Comment: @Shog9 - If a programmer was working on a program to count bunnies and was having trouble with the algorith, "bunnies" as a tag by itself would tell you something about what the programmer is ultimately trying to do, but it tells you nothing about the aspects of the question which are on-topic. Can you explain how "sudoku" is different?

Comment: Because we actually have a term for what you're doing with bunnies - "counting". While [tag:figuring-out-which-numbers-belong-in-a-grid-based-on-sums-of-numbers-already-in-that-grid] is waaay too long for a tag, @Cyborgx37 - and already has a more familiar term associated with it anyway.

Comment: @JDB In order to ask a question on SO, you need at least one tag, and only languages used in questions asked by 1500+ rep users have tags. So if someone under 1500 rep is asking about a Sudoku solver in a language that doesn't have its own tag yet, [tag:sudoku] alone is appropriate, if I'm not misinterpreting responses to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283027/what-tag-to-use-for-question-in-a-new-programming-language).

Comment: @tepples - This question is nearly two years old. The question you are referencing is about two weeks old.

Answer (score 10):

Sudoku is a useful tag. So are many other tags for specific games:

- [tic-tac-toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe)
- [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess)
- [poker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poker)
- [blackjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackjack)

None of these should be deleted. They provide a wealth of information on the kinds of problems a question is attempting to tackle. A question tagged [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku)[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is much more useful than a question simply tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).