# Asking Minecraft questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope

I discovered that there is a [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag on Stack Overflow, and I do not understand how one Minecraft question avoids the Off-Topic flag. I looked at some past questions with this tag, but I am worried about receiving the flag if I asked my own one day. The following segment of the tag description is why I am asking this question:

> Note: Minecraft questions are generally OFF-TOPIC on Stack Overflow.

I am also aware of the [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site and Minecraft Forge forums for asking mod questions, but how do you tailor a Minecraft question to not end up with the Off-Topic flag on Stack Overflow?

Comment: A decent question about some code in a mod you're writing can be perfectly on-topic. The tag [tag:Minecraft] may be irrelevant, though.

Comment: The problem I see is that people working on Minecraft mods generally need support, they're not out to ask a question. Many aspiring modders are quite young and don't even have much of a grasp on Java programming yet to be able to ask an answerable question, they're learning on the go by copying what others do / tell them to do. And that would be where I fully agree with Cerbrus: the minecraft tag is irrelevant. If there is an SO-suitable question to be asked, its either going to be related to Java programming or to a very specific tool/API.

Comment: Hence this [burnination request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310729/).

Comment: It does compete rather poorly with [tic-tac-toe].  Hmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading everyone’s comments and this [spin-off question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310729/), I can conclude that the [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag was never relevant on Stack Overflow anyway. The tag should as well be removed or “burninated”.

If we want to ask questions about developing Minecraft mods in Java, then they would best fit the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag since the tag is relevant to programming. Because Stack Overflow is for programming questions, we can ask Minecraft questions as long as they are about **Java programming problems in mods or server plugins**.

Comment: I disagree that it should be burninated... the tag itself is useful in identifying the specific area that a question may be asking about, *especially* for questions specifically about plugin/raw server development.

Comment: Programming isn't a disconnected exercise. If it were the case, you'd be an expert on anything Java-made just by being an expert on Java. There's a line (a **very** blurry line IMHO) drawn between which of those at-first seemingly irrelevant tags should we let in and which ones we shouldn't.

Answer (score 10):

I can think of a number of good uses of the tag.

Minecraft has a plugin API -- questions about that are on topic.  (one could argue that it is "too narrow" I suppose).

Minecraft allows programming within it ([redstone](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Redstone_circuit)) -- questions about that might be on-topic.  And [amusing](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2011-11/15/notch-game-in-notch-game).

mods, that (I think) decompile the .jar, modify it, then recompile it, would also be on topic.

I cannot imagine that these are the majority of questions, however.

It is true that Minecraft is usually modded/plugged into in java, or in java-bytecode compatible languages.  But that is true of any java-based library; and library-based tags are useful.

Comment: _"(red blocks or somesuch?)"_ Command blocks. Just to help you out. ;)

Comment: @Kendra I was thinking [redstone](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Redstone_circuit).

Comment: I figured you were, though redstone doesn't really qualify as programming in an SO sense. Redstone is _circuitry_ and asking questions about it would most certainly be off-topic on SO. Command blocks, however, are indeed for commands, though I don't think those would be too great to ask about on SO, either. (To be fair though, I haven't played with command blocks much.)

Comment: @Kendra I disagree. Circuitry *is* programming, just at a lower level (closer to the hardware). Logic gates are Turing Complete, after all. It doesn't look as if it would be on topic at the Electric Engineering site, so this one is the best bet.

Comment: @mbomb007 It would get shut down fast here. It'd probably be fine on the gaming site really. Since it is a game mechanic. Redstone circuits really won't fly here I can almost guarantee.

Comment: @Kendra Programming with logic gates? Why not? The OP doesn't have to present the problem as gaming, he can draw up a diagram of the logic gates, etc. It's programming. There are plenty of classes on logic gate programming, so I'd say that form of programming is on topic, at least.

Comment: @mbomb007 Because it's not programming in the sense allowed on SO. Or have you seen circuitry questions allowed in here before?

Comment: @Kendra If the user does a good enough job of wording the question in a certain way, then yeah. There are a few under [tag:circuit] and a few others.

Comment: @mbomb007 I had to refine the search a bit, but there are indeed a few upvoted questions about circuits. (I did not check dates or such, but I'm about to hop off here so didn't have time to.) I concede your point, and see you are correct. Some of them can be on-topic here, it would appear.

Comment: @khendra would a half-adder be off-topic? I mean you program FPGA. I agree this borderline but as long as it's logic only (ie boolean) and not dealing with voltages then it seems like an algorithm an arguabl on topic... byt then problem shouldnt get the minecraft tag...

Comment: Note that Arqade has [a lot of well-received questions about minecraft redstone circuitry and command blocks](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bminecraft-redstone%5D+score%3A1..+closed%3Ano). So there's still a place to ask these questions even if it's decided they're off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask about a technical implementation of the mcforge API or some very deep API interfacing with a particular mod, that is on-topic. That said, these questions gain absolutely nothing from the Minecraft tag, as questions that would be suitable for the API in general would also be merited just on their own as Java programming questions.

I suggest we start a motion to burninate the Minecraft tag, then.

Comment: Sure, but there are currently 931 questions with that tag.  A lot of them are negatively scoring and possibly off-topic, but that's still a decent backlog.

Comment: Writing up a burnination request.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Take a look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273080. (disclaimer: I didn't look at the tag under discussion)

Comment: [That sure is a nice \[minecraft\] tag you have there. It would be a shame if anything happened to it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310729/)

Comment: I could reasonably imagine someone being an expert in minecraft related tech, such as the internals, the network protocol, etc.  If I knew about minecraft and wanted to answer questions about it, I wouldn't want to hunt through every language tag, I'd want to favorite the [minecraft] tag.  I don't see why this should be burninated, it's not a meta tag.  It's like saying [flask] is a meta tag because everyone could just tag the questions [python].

Answer (score 2):

What can we expect to happen from the removal of this tag?

Will kids just learning how to program in Minecraft stop posing questions? Probably not. So you end up probably seeing "Minecraft" more in the titles than the tags, or not at all and just end up seeing the bad question.

The Minecraft-related traffic doesn't necessarily go down with the removal of the tag, and I think the real focus of this is really about the traffic and the low-quality answers associated, not about the tag. Actually that's my thought on half the things I see discussed here -- the real problem is the traffic, and the low-quality questions that can bring.

Take a game-related API that demands considerably more expertise than [unreal-engine4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine4). Is that really so much more on-topic than Minecraft? The difference, as I see it, is that UE 4 tends to just attract more competent/mature developers.

So I really think the tag is fine unless we can somehow show that the Minecraft-related traffic would be mitigated somehow with its removal. I think far more likely is that the traffic will spill out and bleed over more to other areas of the community. I know that's a bad argument ideologically, but I mean, what should we expect?

In general, I think we need to relax a lot of rules for tags. For example, I'd suggest that tags like `design` or `architecture` are equally off-topic, because you tend to find so many questions there which appeal to opinionated answers. They're well-formed questions but ultimately appealing to experienced opinions. But that's the nature of design -- when someone asks if an architectural design choice is good or bad, they're appealing to biased answers, since software design is typically not a perfect science. It doesn't always break down into perfect SE metrics and is often guided by far too many variables including ones like what might best suit the experience level/comfort of the implementor. But I'm on the side that we should relax the general rules of the site and let such questions slide (as they often do) in such tags, since experienced biased answers tend to be appropriate for those tags. So I have a more confederate rather than federal mindset here, so to speak, where each independent tag is like an independent state -- loosely subject to the rules of the federal government, but allowed to kind of evolve in their own direction a bit.