# Sorry, no [dice]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice) tag (x483) seems pretty useless. Tag Description:

> Dice are small objects thrown by hand that land in different positions, used to generate random value for games, particularly gambling.

It mostly seems to consist of questions asked by new programmers that are attempting to make basic dice-rolling games.

- It is used in a wide variety of contexts for all kinds of issues and languages.
- Its description is the definition of dice
- Dice have nothing to do with programming
- Peoples expertise in dice and dice-related activities doesn't matter in the context of a programming Q&A site.

This tag meets most criteria of [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
  *Yes, but not really. It is used for all kinds of questions, that just happen to somehow involve dice*
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? *No*
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? *Nope*
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? *Again, yes but no*

Comment: `Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? No` What else could [tag:dice] refer to other than small objects thrown by hand to generate random values for games?

Comment: @TylerH I would dice that argument in a bit to dice my desktop.

Comment: @Braiam The context of your comment does not work as a response to my question, which is referring specifically to the tag wiki, which uses the primary definition of the word 'dice'. In fact your comment is nonsensical using any definition of the word.

Comment: I think we're all missing the important question here, which is... Are coins dice?

Comment: @BilltheLizard no; dice are polygons. Cylinders are not

Comment: I'm not nearly so sure that it doesn't fit 1 or 4 but it clearly isn't 2 or 3 and that is sufficient for burnination.

Comment: @AlexCollins According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination if a tag passes any of the 4 tests, then it's not appropriate for burnination. Passing two of four is an even more resounding "not appropriate for burnination".

Comment: @TylerH Thanks I was unaware.

Comment: Very related: [Should we burn sudoku?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273080/should-we-burn-sudoku).  Dice games are a common programming task, especially for beginners.  Precedent has been set that game related tags are completely valid and on-topic.  So I don't see why [dice] would be any different.

Comment: @TylerH That is true. However, this is why we take these things on a case by case basis, having the burnination reasons as a *guideline*. Otherwise, S.O. could have a tag for each household object. They mean the same thing across all contexts and are unambiguous. They would remain despite being useless for the site.

Comment: @TylerH no, [ideally a good tag should meet the 4 criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#comment896615_239191), meaning that a tag that fails 1 is reason enough to start a call for action.

Comment: Funny you should mention that - I was actually jut thinking about writing a Meta post on the topic.

Comment: It seems like a pretty [dice]y tag to me.

Comment: @TylerH What else could dice refer to?  When I saw the tag I assumed it was for a dice.com API.  Because that makes a lot more sense as a tag than about dice for gaming, where there's probably 10 questions total you could ever ask.

Comment: @psubsee2003: but soduku, like chess, has a specific set of rules. One can be an expert in strategies codifying those rules. Dice.... not so much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's a reasonable arguement

Comment: @GabeSechan Did you still assume that after reading the tag wiki?

Comment: @stybl I'm not saying I disagree with the proposal, just that we follow the process correctly.

Comment: @Braiam No, the *SO-specific* Meta post I linked to which builds on Shog's SE content on the matter says clearly "if the tag meets any one of them (or more), or if it is clear that removing it will do more harm than good, the request will be declined" for asking the community to burninate. So if OP wants to try and burninate the tag himself, that's one thing. But the community won't help him if it doesn't fall **all four** points.

Comment: @TylerH No, because I didn't bother to read a tag wiki, add the idea of a tag for physical dice is so obviously a bad idea. If it isn't, I demand we rename python to python-language, because I have questions to ask about snakes

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't think whataboutism will serve you well here. It's a simple set of guidelines to meet for community tag burnination. For the record, I think you can probably follow the guidelines and still get to a point where we agree on burninating the tag. But trying to argue that dice means dice-jobs or dice-cooking-technique more than it means dice-RNG is just a waste of your time here.

Comment: Upvote just for the title. Well I also agree with your idea

Comment: @TylerH Its already been established that 1)Those are guidelines not hard rules and 2)You misinterpreted how to use them anyway.  There is no valid argument that dice for physical dice is a good tag, it violates every rule.  The one you might have had a point on is if it was unambiguous-  but as I proved it isn't.

Comment: @GabeSechan I didn't misinterpret them, I explained to Alex and to stybl how they work (*I also helped write them*, btw). But you're still wasting your time in the comments here. If you think questions asking about the kind of things people are using the [tag:dice] tag for need a different or better tag, write an answer here about what they can be re-tagged as. If you just think having a [tag:dice] tag is stupid, that's fine, but you should share that via an upvote to the question, instead.

Comment: @TylerH I did upvote the question.  Now if you excuse me, I'm going to take your new guideline interpretation and go make a lamp tag to talk about lamps.  Because on a programming site those obviously mean light devices and not a web stack.  You're just wasting your time looking like an idiot defending the idea of a dice tag.  I'm actively losing respect for you the more comments you make.  It has NEVER been accepted that being unambiguous is sufficient not to burninate a tag.  And once again, dice is not unambiguous.

Comment: @GabeSechan Almost no single-word tag is unambiguous just by the name. That's why you look at the wiki/description. That's the point of the wiki/description, in cases where words have multiple uses. I can't help it that you don't understand the word dice as well as the rest of us. Stick to the point of the thread which is determining whether the tag *as a whole* (including its wiki/description) is ambiguous, on-topic, etc., and not whether the name of the tag makes you feel warm and fuzzy.

Comment: Be civil guys.. I understand that this is a dicey issue but there is no need for the discussion to get heated

Comment: @TylerH Or you can just admit you were wrong rather than digging yourself deeper.  Its ok, it happens to all of us.  But dice is not unambiguous, and is a horrible tag.  There is no good reason to have a tag about a physical object on a programming site, unless that physical object hooks up to a computer in some fashion.

Comment: @stybl I see what you did there :)

Comment: @GabeSechan I wouldn't waste my time making false admissions. You are still leaving comments that should be answers, though.

Comment: BTW https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_(programming_language)

Comment: @Slai This makes an even better case for renaming the tag

Comment: @Slai Nice catch, but it looks like that language is used mainly by a few classes at Columbia University. I don't think it's notable enough to worry about yet. If we start getting questions about it, _then_ we'd need to rethink things.

Answer (score 26):

Changing the name and rewriting the wiki may be better than burnination.

The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dice/info) says this:

> Dice are small objects thrown by hand that land in different positions, used to generate random value for games, particularly gambling.
>
> A die (plural dice) is a small object (most commonly a cube) designed to be thrown onto a surface. Markings on the face of the die chosen by how it lands indicate a value that is thereby chosen randomly. Dice have been used for centuries--even longer than playing cards--for gambling and other games.

**This is not how the tag is being used in the questions.**

None of the questions are talking about physical dice. The questions are all about *dice simulations*.

Physical dice are off-topic and pretty meaningless. Would you add a [dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice) tag if you needed help with an app that analyzed images to recognize dice? Or maybe if you needed help on your e-commerce site where you sold dice?

Dice simulations *are* on topic, and a [dice-simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice-simulation) tag would add meaning to the question. There are similar tags, such as [cloth-simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloth-simulation) and [traffic-simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traffic-simulation).

**I propose that we rename the tag as [dice-simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice-simulation) and make [dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice) a synonym.**

Now, an argument could be made that [simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simulation) covers dice simulation already. I don't have a strong counter-argument, but having a specific tag for dice seems useful. The [simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simulation) tag is awfully broad. It's possible that someone could start specializing in answering dice simulation questions (though nobody has so far). I'm okay with replacing it entirely with [simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simulation), but I think it's better to go with [dice-simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice-simulation).

Comment: I like dice-simulation. It's going to come up a lot anyway and the algorithms are language agnostic.

Comment: I'm all for specific tags, to replace `dice` with `simulation` feels weird to me, especially since `simulation` is a very broad tag, and it wouldn't add a lot to these questions in my opinion (and there are a lot of broad and more specific tags out there, such as `vba`, `excel-vba`, `access-vba` etc.)

Comment: or replace [tag:dice] with [tag:random-uniform]

Comment: How much use can there possibly be for a dice-simulation tag? I can imagine about one or two questions to which all others could be closed as a dupe. I agree with coeur that random-uniform is much better.

Comment: There are 466 questions in the `dice` tag currently. I don't say that they're all great questions, but I doubt they are all dupes. I would probably be fine with `random-uniform` also; I just haven't given it as much thought.

Comment: @mbrig what about rolling multiple dice and taking a sum?  Those distributions aren't uniform, but curved.  Dice-simulation seems more appropriate.

Comment: @ryanyuyu there is fundamentally no difference between a die and a uniform random generator. Knowing that the user specifically wants to simulate dice does not add anything (as a tag) than knowing they want uniform random numbers between 1-6 (possibly with further manipulations)

Comment: @mbrig you can shortcut the actual rolling of uniform dice by just using a distribution instead.  Instead of generating 2 uniform random numbers and summing them, you can generate that pyramid-looking distribution for a single sum.  I'm also not convinced that random-uniform is easily associated with dice.  At least for a tag name.

Comment: @ryanyuyu But that is still a property of uniform random numbers, rather than a special property of dice. I do agree that random-uniform is not particularly intuitive.

Comment: I just question the value of a tag where I suspect every question can be closed as a duplicate of a more general one about uniform random numbers. You have given me food for thought though, thanks.

Comment: @mbrig I think the point is that the kinds of contexts that dice RNG are used are a bit more focused than a typical uniform RNG.  When I think of dice, I think specifically of integer RNG ranges of 1-6 (or maybe 1-20) often needing to be summed together.  Certainly, you could use exclusively RNG tags, but I think the dice tag is potentially helpful in narrowing the context.

Comment: "Dice simulation" to me sounds like a physics simulation of rolling dice. The analogy with "cloth simulation" only strengthens that association.