# I'll build my own Stack Overflow, with [blackjack] and [unhookwindowshookex]! Well, not really

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

You've probably already guessed why I included that second tag here. It has only 4 questions, so, literally (I mean, figuratively) *nobody's using it*, which means it should definitely be burninated.

Now, a step-brother of the first tag, [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku), has already caused [some debates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273080/4354477), and [blackjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackjack) was mentioned as a tag just as *useful* as [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) in an answer *against* burnination of the latter.

However, I think that [blackjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackjack) should be burninated for the following reasons:

- Blackjack **isn't even on-topic for Stack Overflow**. I mean, yes, one can write algorithms to implement blackjack, but so can they write algorithms to play [patience (solitaire)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patience_(game)), whist, bridge (not to be confused with [bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bridge)) and other card games! Why don't we create a tag for each of these?? Because they're off-topic, obviously. Yet somehow, blackjack and [poker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poker) are not and even have their own tags...
- It only has 250 questions, very few of which actually deal with a problem *specific* to the game (do we actually need to discuss the rules of a card game on a website about *programming* anyway??). Thus, they **can be solved without the knowledge that the askers are dealing with blackjack**. The questions boil down to issues with:

  - syntax
  - data organisation
  - randomisation
- One can be an expert in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [artificial-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)... (I was searching for other useful tags and stumbled upon [pacman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pacman). *Seriously??*) But can you be an expert in blackjack *as a programmer*? Is it so hard to implement or does it have so many applications *in programming* that one could consider themselves a "**blackjack-programmer genius**"?
- Most tags are about fields of programming, different languages, useful concepts, programming paradigms, operating systems, various technologies, etc. You can look at the title of a question and its tags and instantly decide whether you can potentially answer it or not *because it's not your field* or you don't have enough experience with this particular technology. This is also about being an expert, as discussed earlier. Tags allow to filter content based on relatively *broad* concepts. But [blackjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackjack) is **way too concrete a tag**. Do we need such concrete tags at all? If you want to know what concrete problem the OP tries to solve, just open their question and see what it's about - just a couple of clicks!

To sum up, I believe that [blackjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackjack) doesn't add any useful information to a question and should be burninated along with [unhookwindowshookex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unhookwindowshookex) (and, honestly, all the tags about card games, PACMAN and stuff like that).

Comment: Just remember that the request for [removing flappy-bird was declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really).

Comment: @gunr2171, whaaat??? Anyway, it's 2018, guys, time to get rid of useless tags!

Comment: Also, there is [tag:pokemon-go]. _Why??_ With 14 questions! As it was [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47297590/4354477) in an answer to one of them, "you should only post development related questions", Pokémon GO is totally unrelated!

Comment: I think you're not understanding the explanations by Shog9 on those various requests. [a](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273088/1043380) [b](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273081/1043380). It's even built into the [tag burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/1043380) "Your distaste for a frustrating game shouldn't result in the destruction of otherwise-valid tags."

Comment: @ForceBru [Futurama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e35AQK014tI)? :)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, exactly!

Comment: Actually, there are no experts in [tag:atrificial-intelligence]. :)

Comment: @E_net4 did you mean [artificial-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence)?

Comment: @TinyGiant Good question! Did the OP mean [tag:artificial-intelligence]?

Comment: Alternatively, we could keep it fair by raising tags for all the other Windows API calls :)

Comment: @MartinJames: [tag:createwindow] [tag:createwindowex] [tag:registerclass] [tag:showwindow] [tag:peekmessage] [tag:getclientrect] aaaand I got tired of searching. But still, so many to add yet.

Comment: @usr2564301 [sigh].  That's the last time I try to make a humourous comment:(     Can we please flame-thrower all those [already-fully-documented on MSDN] tags and move any useful questions to [winapiI]?

Comment: +1. I am wondering which of thoses blackjack questions can not live without the tag and aren't a candidate for being closes as to broad.

Answer (score 16):

A few notes:

- **The existence of "experts" is a terrible metric for which tags we should keep or destroy.** I've answered questions on plenty of things I'm not an expert on (for example, *every question I've ever answered anywhere*), and most certainly *benefited from browsing* plenty of tags in which I'm neither an expert nor reading expert answers. "Enthusiast programmers" is still part of the site's description; we shouldn't need a monk who has dedicated the past 10 years of their life for every tag.
- There are definitely experts on blackjack. There are definitely experts on writing *software* for blackjack. There are entire industries built around programming software for blackjack. That you don't know this suggests you've done absolutely no research prior to posting this request. I'm not asking you to spend a day learning about it, but... Is 10 seconds searching Google for "blackjack software development" really that much of a burden?
- I assume you just threw in [unhookwindowshookex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unhookwindowshookex) to troll already-beleaguered WinAPI devs, but... [NO TWO-FERS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

Comment: Okay, after I googled that, it turned out that people are indeed going nuts about programming blackjack. Fine, but the SO questions tagged [tag:blackjack] still deal with issues that could arise in any other context, not _necessarily_ blackjack. So, this tag still doesn't add any useful information to a question.

Comment: If a question is mistagged - that is, if the question is not in some way *about blackjack* - then retag that question. That's an entirely different problem. Don't go overboard though; plenty of problems *can* be generalized, but having specific questions is generally useful: knowing that there's a language-agnostic heapsort algorithm is nice, but having a question about its implementation in C++ (and *tagged [tag:c++]*) is also handy.

Comment: "every question I've ever answered anywhere"? Even your meta answers?
 Surely you must be an expert on Stack Overflow by now.

Comment: I'm not sure who could fairly be called a "Stack Overflow expert" at this point, @Don'tPanic - but I wouldn't count myself in that group. It's too big, too complex, with too many odd and interesting corner-cases, unique specialties, and esoteric fields contained within it. Even in areas where I've had a fair bit of involvement, I've probably forgotten or overlooked more than I know. Most answers I write even here still involve some amount of research.

Comment: Well, you always sound like you know exactly what you're talking about. Maybe you're just an expert at that, then? ;)

Comment: That's called "being a jackass", and it's a *style* not an expertise. Go ahead, ask me a question about something I have *zero* knowledge of, like microbiology or Persian typography, and witness the unshakable authoritativeness of my response.

Comment: You mean a BlackJackass?

Comment: I assume he just threw in unhookwindowshookex to [make a punny title](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/im-going-to-build-my-own-theme-park-with-blackjack-and-hookers) rather than troll already-beleaguered WinAPI devs,