# No more credits for [pacman]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [pacman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pacman) tag (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pacman?sort=votes&pageSize=50):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?**

   Questions tagged with "pacman" can live without it. They are generally SDL/pygame questions which could apply to any 2D game, or questions about pathfinding.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Most questions are globally on-topic, but a lot of them:

   - Most may fit well in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ([Pacman: how do the eyes find their way back to the monster hole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148435/pacman-how-do-the-eyes-find-their-way-back-to-the-monster-hole))
   - Some are homework dumps
   - Some are related to pacman package manager
   - Are too broad: example: *[Pacman Ghost moving in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323354/pacman-ghost-moving-in-android)* with a lot of link-only answers to external sites.

3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   - Do we need to create [galaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/galaga) for a question about how to move the aliens AND shooting at the same time?
   - Do we need to create [double-dragon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-dragon) for a question about fighting AI?
   - Do we need to create [ridge-racer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ridge-racer) for a question about programming braking dynamics?

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   People misuse this tag for some questions about MSYS package manager (pacman as well) whereas they should be tagged [pacman-package-manager], for instance that one: *[MSYS2 pacman can't update packages through corporate firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783065/msys2-pacman-cant-update-packages-through-corporate-firewall)*

Six questions with tags [pacman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pacman) and [msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msys2): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pacman+msys2, but there are probably others.

TBH, the mixup with the package manager annoys me the most.

I love pacman, but shouldn't we remove this tag anyway?

Comment: "Game Over for [pacman]" seems a snappier title to me.

Comment: "But one can be an expert in Pacman!"

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, that was my first choice, but there was already "game over" for other gaming related tags.

Comment: I personally have trouble reaching level 12. some go to the infamous split screen, playing through level 256.

Comment: So why does this tag need burninated when other game tags have previously been discussed and declared useful?  [`[blackjack]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362095/) is ok.  As is [`[sudoku]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273080/should-we-burn-sudoku).  I think [chess] has been discussed but can't find it.  So why are these good, but pacman isn't?

Comment: And if you look at the comments in the answer to the [sudoku](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273080/should-we-burn-sudoku) question, you'll see pacman was mentioned and Shog didn't see an issue with it

Comment: there's a specific issue where pacman conflicts with the eponymouns package manager from MSYS2

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre then maybe some renaming the tag is needed then rather than burninating.  I get the conflict issue but if the tag describes the problem in the question then removing it doesn't make sense as it makes it harder to find stuff

Comment: let's see how it goes. that's what discussion is for.

Comment: if someone succeeds in getting the pacman gold badge, I'll delete my question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre unfortunately, before someone can do that, an [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man#Kill_screen) occurs.

Comment: @psubsee2003 There is also a "pacman" package manager in ArchLinux. Disambiguation might be useful for this tag.

Comment: Honestly, that's wasted time. (your time!). Of course we need a pacman tag.

Comment: I favor burninating all game tags (pacman, blackjack, sudoku, chess, etc.) but some really smart people see it otherwise. At the least, "pacman" should be renamed to "pacman-game" or similar to prevent confusion.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm yeah. But good luck playing until that infamous level. See  if you can find some cool "split screen" T-shirts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the key here is this:

**Is there some particular algorithm problem or programming practice unique to the specific tag?**

As in, do the tag fill a purpose in itself? For example, if you tag something [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) then by just using the tag you have stated all requirements for the algorithm. Nothing needs to be said to the reader about the rules about Sudoku if the tag is there, which means more compact questions. Seems like a good tag to have.

This gets more vague for more complex games like Pacman. Is the tag really implying a certain specification or a unique problem? There are a whole lot of different implementations of this game, different rules, different controls, sound, graphics. There is no official "Pacman-standard" as such. So the tag just comes to mean some sort of 2D game where things move along the X and Y coordinates according to some map.

In this case I don't think the tag adds anything, except telling the reader that you are making some sort of game, which might not even be relevant information for solving the specific problem. It risks becoming a useless tag such as for example [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website). "Hi guys I'm making a website. Now here is my specific PHP problem: ..." The part about the website is completely redundant. Similarly, the reader does not need to know that you are making a Pacman game to help you with your memory leak bug.

---

( As a parenthesis, I often use a Pacman anecdote to teach programmers why they should not implement "burn-away-instruction-loops" and busy-wait, as a way to implement software timers.

As a child, I had a 286 and there Pacman ran perfectly. Then we got a 386 and suddenly the difficulty was increased significantly, as both Pacman and the ghosts started to move at much faster speed. At then finally on the 486, you just started the game and Pacman instantly died, because the ghosts moved faster than what the player could even notice. This was caused by poorly-written delay code in the DOS version of Pacman: they had created a tight coupling between the delays and the specific CPU clock, making the game non-portable.

So for me personally, there *is* an unique programming problem that can be illustrated with the Pacman game :) Even though it doesn't justify the tag, sadly. )

Comment: yes there are a lot of CGA-era games which have this issue. I remember a breakout clone which ran so fast you had "game over" in less than a second.

Comment: Pentiums solved the problem again; they became fast enough to emulate an Atari 2600 so you could play the awesome Ms. Pacman on it.

Comment: Pacman/Mrs Pacman just suck on VCS, I use the MAME version since 1997.

Comment: I found the CGA breakout clone name now: PopCorn: http://www.ludoid.fr/site/index.php/popcorn

Comment: Things were different back in those early days.  Each new computer coming out typically wasn't backwards compatible.  Nobody anticipated the same code running on faster (enough to matter to gameplay) hardware.  :-)

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch But the devs already failed to realize that different computers co-existing at the same time had different system clocks. So it is not as easy to dismiss as "they couldn't anticipate it", because the game was already running at slightly different speed on the various co-existing machines. The explanation is rather that the devs were hobbyists creating games for fun, as PC games had zero commercial potential back then. So there was no need for professionalism.

Answer (score 14):

There is plenty of precedent with game tags being acceptable, so why is pac-man any different?

Some examples include

- [blackjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackjack) and [poker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poker) as discussed in  [I'll build my own Stack Overflow, with [blackjack] and [unhookwindowshookex]! Well, not really](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362095/)
- [sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) as discussed in [Should we burn [sudoku]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273080/should-we-burn-sudoku)

[chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess) also exists, as does [tic-tac-toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe), and a host of other specific game tags.  The common theme as to why these tags have been declared useful is they accurately describe the content of the question.

In this case, you have someone developing a pacman game and then need help implementing the algorithm for the ghosts to follow the path through the board.  How are they going to find the best answers?  IF they ask a question, how is someone who has experience writing such an algorithmn going to find the question to answer.

Comment: Also related is flappy-bird: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really

Comment: Pacman is actually mentioned in the first link.

Comment: Pacman ghosts use a rather ingenious AI solution. They don't pathfind at all! But such things are better suited to Game Dev SE.