# Dis-[connect-four] better tagging

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

We should remove the [connect-four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect-four) tag. This is a game and doesn't really add much to the post. While we do have [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess), there is a much wider audience.

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  Yes it does. It ambiguous if ever a library would be named that.
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Not directly. There are better descriptive tags surrounding games and logic.
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  Not really, only describes the problem domain, but could be described more generally.
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  It could be different across cultures due to it being a registered trademark.

Comment: There are currently only 18 questions with the most part already on the way to be Roomba'd. This doesn't require a burnination. Just a retag

Comment: How is 'connect-four' related to programming? or Chess? It seems more like an example for AI Programming.

Comment: @PCM not at all directly

Comment: Why should `chess` have a `monopoly` on game tags?

Comment: I would also throw [tag:tic-tac-toe] in the mix.

Comment: I recall there was [a similar discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273080/2821954) about Sudoku and [other games](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/273080?sort=newest).

Comment: Tic-Tac-Toe is almost the canonical example of a game that admits simple computer implementations (indeed, it was one of the [very first games implemented on a computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OXO)), and is widely used for tutorials and examples on how to write algorithms for games (and the different approaches for that). Connect Four definitely is not (and Connect Four is actually not simple in terms of optimal solutions). Regardless of whether Connect Four deserves its own tag, I don't think `tic-tac-toe` should be thrown into any kind of mix.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would very much throw tic-tac-toe into the same mix as chess.

Comment: @MegaIng: OK, that wasn't clear from your comment. (The "chess" comment by Adrian was just for pun, so I didn't think you were referring to that.)

Answer (score 14):

### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?

> Yes it does.

We are in agreement about that.

### Is it unambiguous?

> It ambiguous if ever a library would be named that.

To me it seems that we shouldn't worry about that until it actually happens which I think is unlikely.

### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

> Not directly. There are better descriptive tags surrounding games and logic.

A lot of questions tagged [connect-four] could be on-topic for the site. I did notice that a lot of questions tagged [connect-four] are off-topic but I think those questions would still be asked if the tag were burminated.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

> Not really, only describes the problem domain, but could be described more generally.

I agree that it could be described more generally but I doubt that without the [connect-four] tag people will be more likely to include other tags

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

> It could be different across cultures due to it being a registered trademark.

I have looked at the questions tagged [connect-four] and I have not found any which were not talking about the game so I am skeptical.

## In conclusion, I don't think this tag should be burninated.

Comment: I think the only point that’s really up in the air is ”is the concept on-topic for the site?” and if chess is OK, then the fact that it’s a game doesn’t disqualify it. But are there common problems to connect-four implementations or strategies that make it worthwhile to keep around as a tag? I’m afraid the game is rather too simple for that.

Comment: We also have [tag:tic-tac-toe]. Maybe a more general term for all of these games would be nice?

Comment: @MegaIng What about [simple-game-programming] or something?

Comment: @PCM I don't like that. I would put focus on the fact that these tags are interesting if they pertain to implementing an AI.

Answer (score 2):

I goofed and nearly burninated the tag before I realized [we've had this discussion before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273088/2370483)

> Presumably it could be useful to folks writing clones of the "Flappy Bird" game—an activity that, for whatever reason, appears to be somewhat popular.

Or, more to the point, [Shog9 dismissed burnination points one and two on the sudoku tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273081/2370483).

> It clearly identifies a specific set of problems and folks use it more or less exclusively to refer to those problems.

I've fixed that error on my part and restored the tag to those I had removed (some low quality posts are gone for good, tho). I've also given it a proper excerpt. Remember, [there's a fair number of questions asking how to write programs like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22connect+four%22+is%3Aq&searchOn=3).

Comment: "we've had this discussion before" And the argument is still silly. We don't use tags for the objective (yes, I know they exist, that doesn't meant they should). Otherwise I should start using banking, inventory management, data analysis, diseases classification, etc. for every question I ask on the site (these are related to my day job). Describing the end goal is done in the body of the question, to explain the context, but I've never seen a question where knowledge outside of the language/framework is necessary to answer a well through out question.