# You should [readme]: this tag is useless

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [readme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readme) tag has around 200 questions, which are mainly [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown)-related, but they are all around the place.

The description reads:

> A readme file is a file that contains information about something that should be read, generally before use.

Sounds pretty vague and useless for me. It's not even about programming.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes, all the questions I've seen are about README.txt/README.md files.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It doesn't describe the contents at all, usually it's about formatting the file, but not necessarily. Therefore, it's not unambiguous either.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, not at all. It's irrelevant that the file is a readme file.

**Is the topic described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, but the tag itself is not about programming. Anything can have a readme file.

**Is the tag harmful?**

Not really, but it's not useful either.

Comment: *[README](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/README)* - *"A README file contains information about other files in a directory or archive of computer software. A form of documentation ... text file called Read Me, READ.ME, README.TXT, README.md (Markdown markup), README.1ST – or simply README. ... Contents ... Configuration instructions. Installation instructions. ... Copyright and licensing information, Contact ... programmer. Known bugs. ... A changelog (usually for programmers. ... the* ***GNU Coding Standards*** *encourage including one to provide 'a general overview of the package'".*

Comment: It is related to programming, but perhaps too vaguely.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mean, if you're gunna argue a readme is related to programming you might as well argue a generic book is related to programming

Comment: @Nick: For 50 years it has been a consideration before putting out software in the public. What should the documentation for the software be? How should the documentation be packaged / distributed? It is part of open source culture.

Comment: Yeah, and instruction manuals have no doubt been a consideration before putting out any old piece of hardware like a pump, a generator, maybe even a self-assemble piece of furniture for longer than that. They're the same thing. It's not possible to be an expert in read me's, the tag is worthless

Comment: Not that I'm against this burnination request but the fact that it's not possible to be an expert in something doesn't necessarily mean that the tag is worthless. Otherwise, we should also burninate tags like [[list\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) or [[string\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string). CC: @Nick

Comment: @41686d6564 IMO those should be burninated or split as well.

Comment: @TamásSengel Tags serve other purposes besides having experts follow them and answer questions about them. An important one is making it easier to search for and categorize posts based on tags. There's a reason the [string] tag has over 167K questions. See: [Should we delete the \[string\] and \[array\] tags because they have no experts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255242/8967612)

Comment: @41686d6564 I disagree with that approach, especially since tags like [swiftui-list] exist among these generic tags. Making an automated process that would create additional tags like [(programming language)-array] based on some requirements would be a nicer approach to solve this problem. I know that string algorithms exist that are specifically about strings, but wouldn't it be more logical to tag the specific algorithm there?

Comment: I've seen many worse tags than this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and they still exist today :( (looks at web nervously).

Comment: What makes readme any different from [tag:text-files] processing-wise? If it's about situation, when readme file is a part of documentation/distribution/protocol system, then it's enough to use that system tag, e.g [tag:github].

Comment: @Sinatr there's nothing special about the structure of a readme file (unless it's .md, .rst, etc.).

Comment: There should be an exclusive Stack Exchange site for README.md and generally for markdown because markdown isn't considered a programming language but a formatting/markup language instead.

Comment: @NStavrakoudis that's ridiculous. You can't suggest that without suggesting *all* formatting and markup language questions go on a separate site. JSON, YAML, XML, HTML, HCL, INI... the list goes on. The fact is that `markdown` is very common in the documentation space, and documentation is very important in the software development lifecycle.

Answer (score 41):

Yeah... this tag doesn't have any utility, and should be removed. At only ~230 questions, it shouldn't take too much of an effort either.

#### [readme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readme) Tag Stats

##### Top Mutually-Used Tags ([Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=readme))

| # | Tag | Times Used w/ [readme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readme) | Percent Usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) | 139 | 62% |
| 2 | [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) | 70 | 31% |
| 3 | [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) | 21 | 9% |
| 4 | [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) | 20 | 9% |
| 5 | [github-flavored-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-flavored-markdown) | 19 | 9% |

##### Scores (All time, with deleted posts; [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1409524/average-score-of-all-qs-as-in-tag?TagName=readme))

| Type | Quantity | Median Post Score | Posts Scored ≤0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Questions | 228 | 1 | 97 (42.5%) |
| Answers | 339 | 1 | 109 (32.2%) |

##### Answered/ Accepted Rates

- Answered Rate: ~78%
- Acceptance Rate: ~53%

---

Based on what I've seen looking through questions with this tag, the vast majority of them are about (usually basic) Markdown syntax, which don't benefit from this tag. There's nothing special about Markdown used in Readme's over that which is used in any other Markdown file.

We already have adequate tags for these questions:

- For GitHub-specific questions, there's [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) and [github-flavored-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-flavored-markdown).
- For questions about *generating* a readme, there's [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation).
- For generic Markdown inquiries, there's, of course, [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown).

At the end of the day, I just don't see this tag as being a useful category for bringing experts to questions. We have much better, more specific tags available, that are more related to the actual problems at hand, than [readme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readme).

I vote burn away .

---

##### Addendum

The 3 [most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/how-to-add-images-to-readme-md-on-github) [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509830/how-to-add-color-to-githubs-readme-md-file) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575680/new-lines-inside-paragraph-in-readme-md) in this tag, and also *8* of the top 10 by votes, are specifically about the GitHub Readme, whether syntax, features, locations, etc. These are genuinely useful questions, but they don't warrant the existence of this generic tag.

The way I see it, this tag is essentially akin to a [main.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/main.js) or [index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/index.html) tag, where the file itself is included in many projects, but content is always different, and 99% of the questions regarding such files are generic to the file type. I don't think it should stick around, attracting questions that largely boil down to poorly labeled duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

I disagree with burnination.  I believe this tag is useful. It does not fail all the burnination criteria -- the OP acknowledged it fails the first one.

Per the Burnination criteria, since the tag doesn't fail all the criteria, it should not be burninated.

Further discussion seems to fly in the face of this standard.  But should you wish to ignore the burnination criteria and judge the tag on its merits as if there were no such criteria, read on.

##### It means the same thing in all common contexts

The OP acknowledged, and [@Peter-Mortensen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen) elaborated in the comments, that the README file (with various extensions) is a longstanding key element of coding.  When I first started teaching myself to compile others' code, I knew to go to that file for usage instructions to get started, even if it just told me which other files to read in which order.

It doesn't mean anything else, at least in a programming context. It's unambiguous.

##### It (helps to) describe the contents of the question

I disagree with the second comment that it doesn't describe the contents.  It very specifically identifies that a user is concerned with the content of a very specific file that the user knows others will interact with when attempting to use their software.

The README file is unique.  It's like the first page of a book, where a tag generic to all pages wouldn't apply.

The "Desktop" folder on various operating systems is equally special. Questions relating to folders in general do not have the same context surrounding a folder that, by name and specific location, has a uniquely special interpretation and has [unique questions with an associated tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdesktop%5D&searchOn=3).

The [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) tag by itself is insufficient; there are multiple flavors.  Combining it with [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) or using [github-flavored-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-flavored-markdown) might almost suffice, except that the README is a unique file which prompts unique questions including (from a brief scan of the first page of results):

- Forcing uncached content so users will always see the newest content (a versioning concern)
- Where to locate the file to achieve particular results (a concern with customized rendering using software conditionals)
- Configuring software that auto-generates this file

That's just the first page.

There are [sites devoted to best practices for Github READMEs](https://gist.github.com/akashnimare/7b065c12d9750578de8e705fb4771d2f), and [templates for READMEs](https://github.com/dbader/readme-template) that show content important to programmers that goes far beyond basic Markdown.

##### It's not just about GitHub

Not all readme questions are github specific.  There's questions for [Docker Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134275/), [Nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088571/), [Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107121/), [pub.dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017182/), [npmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595114/) and more.

##### It adds meaningful information to the post

It is useful to know whether we are asking about the entry page or Markdown in comments, issues, FAQs, or other pages.

##### It *is* possible to be an expert

It looks like [@VonC has answered 14 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:6309%20%5Breadme%5D%20is:answer).  [@Chris has answered 11](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:354577%20%5Breadme%5D%20is:answer) including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980639/specify-alternate-project-level-readme-md-on-github/49981731#49981731) that I doubt a non-expert could answer. What other tag is appropriate for that specific question?

##### I personally have used the tag to search

As an open source project maintainer I have repeatedly searched for how to do things in Markdown on the front page of my site that hundreds of people read every day.  I doubt I am the only one who has done so.  There are high-quality questions and answers in the [readme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readme) tag.

##### The tag is not harmful

The OP admits the tag is not harmful, generally treated as replacing other, more relevant tags.  Very few of the tagged questions used the full quota of tags.

The OP's "but..." statement that it is not useful, however, is wrong.

Comment: It only shows that VonC is a GitHub expert rather than a readme expert.

Comment: @user202729 See the specific answer by Chris that I linked and tell me what tags would apply to that expert-level knowlege.  The `github` and `markdown` tags by themselves are insufficient.

Comment: I agree with @user202729. If I want to rename my README.md file to DONOTREADME.md file, it's going to be the exact same file. If GitHub expects a specific name, then the [tag:github] tag is what should be used, since it's a GitHub question specifically.

Comment: What in the world would constitute expert-level knowledge specifically of README files?  What is there to know about them that is neither context dependent nor characteristic of the format in which they are written?

Comment: There's only 77 questions with accepted answers with positive score. Kinda a stretch to say there's many high-quality questions and answers.

Comment: It's kinda a stretch to say "this tag doesn't have any utility" and it's kinda a stretch to say that it's "irrelevant" that a file  a special file designed to be the front page of github site.

Comment: @DanielWiddis it's only special on Github. On my desktop is nothing more than an ASCII text file.

Comment: @braiam "On your desktop" means "In your Desktop folder on your filesystem."   Which is just a folder, nothing special about it.  It's only special on your operating system. No need for [`desktop`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=%5Bdesktop%5D&searchOn=3) tag at all.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I respect that the GitHub Readme use-case for this tag is a valid one; I also just don't see *any* other great use-cases where [[tag:readme]] would add anything of note. *One* good usage doesn't necessitate a tag of its own, and this tag isn't specific to the GitHub case anyway. If categorizing questions about the GitHub-specific Readme file was useful, then we should have a [github-readme] tag; at the moment [[tag:readme]] doesn't usefully describe the vast majority of questions that use it.

Comment: The `readme` tag adds no useful information to the majority of the questions currently tagged with it. Most of them are questions of how to use markdown, or how to do something with a text file that just happens to be a readme file, but in most (if not all) cases the fact that the file in question is a README is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielWiddis no, on the most common operative system in the world and how every program sees it: application/text: ASCII. If it had .md at the end, it would be a markdown file. If it had rst it would be a reStructuredText format. README files are no different from any text file. That's the point. Github being helpful and showing you any README\.?(md|rst|etc. file formatted is something that is [unique to github](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md). If I was using git-web, [I wouldn't get that.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/)

Comment: @Braiam I was talking about your desktop.  It's just a folder in a filesystem. It doesn't deserve its own tag.  I don't care what files you put in it. There's nothing special about that folder.

Comment: @Herohtar Then the majority of quesetions are mistagged. And the tag should be removed from those mistagged questions and left only on questions where it is relevant. Oh, wait, once you bring something up on Meta as a burnination request you can't take any action to moderate it until it's approved. Guess they're stuck like that until this tag ever gets burninated, which will probably be never, so this very request has made the problem worse.

Comment: @zcoop98 Not all readme questions are github specific.  There's questions for [Docker Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134275/), [Nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088571/), [Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107121/), [pub.dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017182/), [npmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595114/) and more.

Comment: I'm talking about the file. The readme file, which isn't a readme file, but a text file which name happens to be readme (said name set by metadata of the filesystem, btw).

Comment: @Braiam and I'm talking about the folder. The Desktop folder, which isn't a Desktop folder, but a folder which name happens to be Desktop.  Which, if it happens to be in a certain special location actually does something different than folders named Desktop in other random locations, like on someone's Desktop.

Comment: You contradict yourself, it is ambiguous. the linked questions regarding different platforms all ask some platform-specific problem, none of which bears similarity other than the name "readme".

Comment: @DanielWiddis I'm sorry if I was unclear, I didn't mean to imply that this tag was *only* used for GitHub readme questions; I simply wanted to acknowledge that this tag has some good questions in it, and that many of the best, most viewed, most upvoted questions in the tag are about GitHub readme's specifically (the top 3 questions in the tag all concern that specific topic; this is in addition to the fact that over half of [[tag:readme]] questions are also tagged [[tag:github]]).

Comment: By itself, the `readme` tag tells me nothing certain about the question. It could be related any number of things: github, a repository, some software, etc. And there is no formal standard that says a readme file **has** to be markdown. Even the wiki tag is extremely broad: _"...a file that contains information about something that should be read..."_. Burnintate it.

Comment: *"What other tag is appropriate for that specific question?"*... `github`, and only that tag. It requires an expert on *GitHub* to explain where GitHub looks for a specific file (which just happens to be README in this case). An "expert in READMEs" (whatever that is) wouldn't be able to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Playing devil's advocate here, the tag has several uses:

Firstly, let me establish that having a readme file is standard practice, and a good one at that. It is also a common default on GitHub as we know.

We will have several questions from newbie programmers about READMEs and about md (markdown) files. They are simple questions to answer, but the question then becomes does SO want to have these simple questions, and I would argue yes, SO *does* want to encourage newbies to ask questions. If they're not popular, they won't rise to the top, people won't waste their time on them, but if they are useful, then others will get to see them; it's the evolution of a forum website.

As for the tag itself, people asking questions about readmes may not know what tag to use, and this tag may fit best.

Additionally, it's a valid tag for questions *about what to include in a readme file in general* which are completely valid questions, just like code review and best practices, or documentation are valid questions.

I generally think the tag is useless, but may as well have a discussion with valid counterpoints. I think the last point I listed that there are potential valid questions for the tag is a strong one.

Comment: "*for questions about what to include in a readme file in general which are completely valid questions*" Actually no, they sound like open-ended / opinion-based / discussion-type questions, which are off-topic for SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. It's not that SO doesn't want simple questions, but more of some questions don't work well with SO's format.

Comment: @GinoMempin exactly, and those are exactly the questions you would just type into google and take the first 2-4 guides that pop up. Instead of going to SO.

Comment: To Gino's point above, "*just like code review and best practices*" questions *aren't* on-topic on SO, so that diminishes that point. I don't think questions about Readme's *have* to be basic necessarily, and SO doesn't (shouldn't) have anything against "basic" questions as long as such questions otherwise fit our guidelines (mainly being detailed, specific, & answerable). There are undeniably some _great_ questions in this tag, the problem is that those questions are categorized together simply because they deal with a file that has the same name, and nothing else.

Answer (score -2):

While not technically a programming topic, `README` files very much have a place within the software development lifecycle.

First, they serve as documentation and have a use for documentation-related questions. Yes, there is the `markdown` tag but not all `README` files are in `markdown` format. It may not be a common tag but it does have a use, classification, and purpose. `README` files also often have considerations for content as they *ideally* should not be very long or serve as complete documentation.

Second, does it meet the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071)?

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **Yes. Even if a question is more about `markdown` than the `README` itself, it gives some additional context around the question in a visible way which is consistent with Stack Overflow's content classification standard.**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **Yes, as stated README files are a specific area of documentation and very much play a role in the software development lifecycle.**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **Yes. A question tagged as both `[readme]` and `[markdown]` tells me the asker is intending to use markdown to format a `README` file. Omitting `readme` could mean the asker is asking about using `markdown` in another context and as such formatting considerations specific to a `README` context may not be considered in my answer. The same logic can be applied to `readme` when paired with other tags as well.**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **Inarguably, yes. I can't think of more than one definition of a `README` file as it pertains to software development, or even across general computing. It is an information document which should be reviewed prior to operation, often (but not exclusively) summarized with redirection to more complete documentation.**

I will agree `readme` is often, if not always, going to overlap with other categories. But I feel it does not meet the criteria for burnination nor do I feel this is a shortcoming with the burnination criteria itself. It's not a common tag, but it has its place.