# Merge [admin] and [administrator]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

We currently have two separate tags [admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin) and [administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administrator). Neither tag seems particularly useful, but we definitely don't need both.

Comment: Do we need either of these tags?

Comment: @VLAZ Nope. There's a burn request from 2014: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254551/6296561

Comment: This is a bit far-fetched, but note that some systems call the admin `admin`, others call them `administrator` (and others call them root). There might perhaps be some programmer context such as multi-platform portability, where these are two different terms? However the current tag wikis don't mention subtle stuff like that, so maybe a merger is the way to go.

Comment: And we apparently also have [tag:root]. Should probably be burninated for the same reasons, or at least disambiguated.

Comment: @pppery I agree that [root] needs to be disambiguated. The tag wiki says it's for questions abut the root user on Unix systems, but most questions with the tag seem to be about rooted Android devices (which is related, but shouldn't be the same tag in my opinion). And searching for `root` at https://stackoverflow.com/tags shows several tags that need to be synonymized, for example [rooted] -> [rooted-device]. And for the Unix root user, we already have [root-access] (which is less popular than [root] but also less ambiguous).

Comment: The "admin" tag is also used in CMS like WordPress to designate the backend (administrative interface) and "administrator" is a user role that has all capabilities (privileges). So I am not for merging those 2.

Comment: That, at best, means there should be [tag:wordpress-admin] and [tag:wordpress-administrator] tags, if those concepts are even on-topic here as opposed to [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 2):

I'm for merge now as a fast action, and let the burn debate continue until settled in due course.

I don't have a particularly good reason other than we can do merge now while the burn has to wait in line.